# Как создать сделать список bean'ов и передать его в качестве property?

Tags: java, spring, xml

Имеем XML, из которого я вынес в отдельный файл список

```
<util:list id="listA" value-type="ru.package.MyClass1">
       <bean p:field1="Value1" p:id="id1" сlass="ru.package.MyClass1"/>
</util:list>
```

В отдельной XML я импортирую этот файл

```
<import resource="classpath:/myLists/myList.xml"/>
```

И передаю в качестве аргумента другому bean

```
    <bean id="aggregatedBean" class="ru.package.MyClass2">
        <property name="prop1"><ref bean="listA"/></property>
    </bean>
```

Так же есть дочерняя XML, которая расширяет `aggregatedBean`, но там список явно указан

```
    <bean id="aggregatedBeanChild" class="ru.package.MyClass2">
        <property name="prop1"><list merge="true">
              <bean p:field1="Value2" p:id="id2" сlass="ru.package.MyClass1"/>
        </list></property>
    </bean>
```

При запуске получаю

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot merge with object of type [class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference]`

Comment: Я спрошу, тем не менее. Почему вы не хотите использовать AnnotationContextConfiguration?

Comment: @Anastasiya Ну, так решили 4-5 лет назад архитектор проекта